# Fedora 31 logs out after I login (Failed NVidia Driver Installation)

Tags: linux, fedora

I have a Fedora install that's a few days old. Today I did the first `dnf update` on the system and it downloaded 1GB of updates.

After rebooting the new kernel and the old one in grub. I get the same result,a t the GUI login screen after I enter my username and password it starts to load, the username/pass prompt disappear, the gray background turns darker gray, then blue. The wallpaper shows, then it flashes back to the login screen.

In runlevel3, running dnf update again updated three packages; microcode_ctl, tzdata, and tzdata-java.

Same thing after trying a few times, one of the times Gnome flashed something at the top of screen "Sorry...." and I think it said something crashed but before I could read the whole message, the system flashed back to the login screen.

I was able to press CTRL+ALT+F2 and access the terminal that way as well, I added a new user using the terminal and am logged in as that user temporarily to use the system to post this.

I rsync'ed my home directory on the first account from my old SSD, that didn't seem to be a problem at first, I could try rsync'ing it to my new account and see what happens, but if there is a log or something I could view to narrow down what it is that is specifically causing this.

Edit:When I try to run this on my new account (not sure the package name in yum/rpm) it logs me out. I could see this being the culprit if my other account is set to launch this on startup.
[image: Compiz_Package]

Edit: -- post GPU here --
Does this provide any beneficial information?

```
lspci | grep -i NVidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

EDIT: On my new account I ran `su username -` and got a terminal as my main account. I was able to run `gnome-tweaks` and disable starting the Compiz icon until I get the NVidia drivers working.

EDIT: Following https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/#before-installation I am getting errors
[image: DKMS Error]

```
 tail /var/log/nvidia-installer.log
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=5.6.13-200.fc31.x86_64 module KERNEL_UNAME=5.6.13-200.fc31.x86_64; make -C uvm module KERNEL_UNAME=5.6.13-200.fc31.x86_64 KBUILD_EXTMOD=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/340.108/build/uvm...........(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.6.13-200.fc31.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/340.108/build/make.log for more information.
-> error.
ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more information.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
[root@host ~]# tail /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/340.108/build/make.log
scripts/Makefile.build:44: ../Makefile: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '../Makefile'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1683: ..] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.6.13-200.fc31.x86_64'
NVIDIA: left KBUILD.
nvidia.ko failed to build!
make[1]: *** [Makefile:197: nvidia.ko] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/340.108/build'
make: *** [Makefile:221: ../Module.symvers] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/340.108/build/uvm'
```

It said Kernel Preparation unnecessary for this kernel could not build the kernel module, when I try to install again it gives a warning about the driver already  being installed and asks if I want to reinstall. When I try to start graphical runlevel 5 using NVidia driver or Nouveau I get this error screen:

[image: Graphical Runlevel 5 Error]

Comment: Try to boot on the terminal mode, go on the grub and edit the boot options and add **3** at the line end of the cmd **linux** like in this [tutorial](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-boot-into-linux-command-line), then log on as root and try to run **dnf update** again.

Comment: dnf update updated three packages; microcode_ctl, tzdata, and tzdata-java

Comment: When I logged in again it still shown the same symptoms. I tried a few times, one of them Gnome flashed something at the top of the screen "Sorry.." and I think it said something crashed but before I could read the full message the system flashed back to the login screen.

Comment: I added a new user using the terminal and am logged in as that user temporarily to use the system to post this.

Comment: I was able to get into runlevel 3 using grub and updated, upon being presented the same symptoms I pressed CTRL+ALT+F2 to access the terminal that way and created a temp user account. (Problem is the keycap for F1 on this keyboard is missing somewhere so I had to press CTRL+ALT+DELETE and reboot :[ )

Comment: I was trying to install my Nvidia drivers https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/ and it said to update, but before I could even try to install the drivers I got this. Should I install the drivers as root, would this help or hinder and make things more complicated and I should wait until after we fix this first?

Comment: I strongly advise you to add the **build setup** on the question, mainly the **GPU specs** before of doing anything,

Comment: Would that be a separate question or should I add details here?

Comment: Just add the details required on this question.

Comment: How would I get the GPU? Would the output of  `lspci | grep -i NVidia` be beneficial?

Comment: On more thing, did you already back up your files? That one's highly recomended.

Comment: This thing came with a HDD (256GB I think). I previously installed a 3TB data HDD. The files from the original HDD were copied to the 3TB HDD. I got a 128GB SSD and installed Fedora 20 onto that (Stock HDD has Win7-->Win10 Free Upgrade and Fedora 14). I had to unplug the stock HDD (which is failing so good idea anyway) to plugin the new SSD I am booting Fedora 31 off of. The old SSD contains my Fedora 14 install whose home directory was copied to the new SSD, contains a folder with Music copied from other machines. The 3TB HDD basically is my backup, or one of them.

Comment: I guess you can say I have a star topology backup system.

Comment: Are there any other files I need to backup, is there a way I can check/remove Gnome startup apps from the terminal ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108683/discussion-between-jluizsouzadev-and-ubuntuforums-staff-are-trolls).

Comment: Are you still in chat? I updated the question with new issues I am facing and information. I tail'ed the log but that only shows 10 lines and might not be enough. Should I post the whole log?